# A question related to vector spaces and cyclic modules.

Tags: vector-spaces, modules

Let $V$ be a vector space over the field $F$ and $T\in \mathcal L(V)$,then $V$ is an $F[X]$-module with the scalar multiplication $p(X).v=p(T)v$.

Now let us come to another definition. For a module $M$ over the ring $R$ and for $x\in M$ define $Rx=\{r.x:r\in R\}$. We say that $M$ is a cyclic $R$-module if $M=Rx$ for some $x\in M$.I am looking for a necessary and sufficient condition that $V$ as $F[X]$-module is cyclic. Can someone help me to find such a condition?

My guess is that there should exist $v\in V$ such that $\{p(X).v:p\in F[X]\} $ is the whole vector space $V$. But can I do anything more simple?